# Google Directions train timetable coverage by country

Tags: metadata, public-transport

I'm trying to figure out which countries in Europe that Google Directions has full coverage for with regards to train timetables.

I found this section: https://maps.google.com/landing/transit/cities/index.html but it isn't easy to understand (`Multi-Region` seems to mean both "many regions/cities in a country" and "the entire country") and in some cases the expected output given the list doesn't match the actual output of Google Directions.

Is there any other, better mapping of train timetable coverage by country in Google Directions out there? Or any resource that can help me determine *if* Google Directions has full coverage of a country's train timetable(s)?

Comment: On a personal note, I would never rely on Google Transit for train timetables.  Even where it has them, they are quite incomplete, and I've seen them suggest connections that are too short.

Comment: Do you have any alternatives? I need to be able to determine *if* you can travel from a random station in a European country to another station in the same country.

Comment: HAFAS is pretty good and can be most easily accessed through bahn.de, but also via the Dutch, Swiss, or Austrian travel planners.  I believe HAFAS is open data.  In southern or eastern Europe HAFAS is not complete, though, but I think RZD is pretty good in CIS/EAEU, no clue if their data are open.

Answer (score 1):

HAFAS is pretty good and can be most easily accessed through https://www.bahn.de, but also via the Dutch, Swiss, or Austrian travel planners. I believe HAFAS is open data accessible by API, but I'm not entirely sure about that. In southern or eastern Europe HAFAS is not complete, though, but I think RZD is pretty good in CIS/EAEU, no clue if their data are open.

One thing that HAFAS does better than Google Transit (from experience) is to know minimum times to change at train stations.  Some stations are huge and connections will only be guaranteed if at least X minutes transfer, but Google Transit may happily suggest a 4 minute transfer at a station where it physically takes longer than that to walk from one platform to another.  At least I've seen that in some cases in the past; this may have improved.